# WebLogic to JBoss migration

Tags: jboss, migration, weblogic, jboss7.x

In my application I have few things which are specific for WebLogic. Is there any tool which can tell me these specification while migrating the application to JBoss?

Comment: Did you look at the JBoss page for this? http://www.jboss.org/migration/platforms/weblogic/ Yes there are tools out there like Windup. http://planet.jboss.org/post/windup_migration_from_oracle_weblogic_to_jboss

Comment: jboss.org/migration is quite old, please refer to [windup.jboss.org](http://windup.jboss.org).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are doing migrations to JBoss you should look at the Windup tool. It will point out all the places in your code that may need attention and give you a score based on how many things you will need to look at. The reports are nice and categorized and they definitely cover your usage of vendor specific code and suggests hints as to what to convert to.

**http://windup.jboss.org/**

There is also a maven plugin that you can add to your pom and run reports periodically as you go.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you Jyore, I did used Windup, Windup was the tool exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it fit your need :)